# Why is my DOM div created as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to create some code to work. However, I keep getting errors, and I have been stuck with this for a while now and in need of help. Whenever the image gets an attempt to be added to the page, I get:

```
<undefined src='(this is where the filepath is listed)'><undefined>
```

Why are the tags not coming out as div?

Css Code:

```
.clock{
    background-image:url('');
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 250px; width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
#myUL{
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
    }
```

Html Code:

```
<input type='file' id='getval' />
<span onclick="readURL()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
<div class='clock'></div>
<div id='myUL'></div>
```

Script code:

```
function readURL(){
    var file = document.getElementById("getval").files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(){
         var div = document.createElement(div);
         div.setAttribute("src", "url(" + reader.result + ")");
         div.class = 'clock';
         document.getElementById('myUL').appendChild(div);
    }
    if(file){
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }else{}
}
```

Comment: There's no attribute src for div

Comment: You need to pass `div` as a string `var div = document.createElement('div');`

Comment: Also use className. class is reserved.

Comment: You are passing the *variable* `div` to `.createElement(div)`, and the variable has the value `undefined` at that point.

Comment: I made changes like you guy suggested, I have another problem now, the image could not be loaded... I'm trying to debug this problem. But its confusing since the code is being generated with the local filepath, however, it is unable to be loaded... do you guys know why it is refusing to load?

Comment: @user3435505 Div doesnt have a src attribute, you should use img instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var div = document.createElement(div); // <<< (div) is a variant.
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/3L53bzx5/1/

```
reader.onloadend = function() {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute("src", reader.result);
  img.className = 'clock';
  document.getElementById('myUL').appendChild(img);
}
```

Comment: You forget to change class by className

Answer (score 0):

You have to change below line

```
var div = document.createElement(div);
```

to

```
   var div = document.createElement('div');
```

in your readURL() method.